# How LXC implements network namespace?

Tags: linux, networking, lxc, linux-namespaces

I would like to know how LXC implement network namespace. One particular aspect is how it connects the virtual interface in a namespace to the physical interface. Assume that the network in a namespace connects to a veth, and the root namespace uses eth0, how does LXC connect veth to eth0? Does it use Linux bridge, or OpenVswitch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to connect containers to the network, described [here](https://wiki.debian.org/LXC#Setup_networked_containers). I always use the SimpleBridge method, because it's easy to setup and I never had any problems with it.